# ggplot2 does not connect points correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have a problem in ggplot2. It fails to connect correctly points.

The points are:

```
Y_Value X_Value
11,28722382 130,9169466
11,33209991 136,0021971
12,87083524 139,7313807
13,87191672 142,1610003
16,89631805 146,2009493
20,27088036 150,5234121
17,57803852 150,0431385
16,89684937 153,0377859
13,21146656 153,9700818
12,37363526 157,0212321
15,50079491 164,1970854
```

Y_value is percentual ("," is the separator for decimals)
X_value is numerical ("," is the separator for decimals)

How can i resolve this problem?

I post 2 images too for look the problem

1. with ggplot2

[image: ggplot2 connected points]

2. with a calc-sheet

[image: calcsheet connected points]

Comment: Where does calc-sheet get the information for this plot from? This looks, frankly, completely invented. In fact, *this isn’t even a valid graph* (of a function mapping real numbers x to y). The graph made by ‘ggplot2’ is the correct one.

Comment: Also please post all the data, calculation and code used so others can help. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Where is your ggplot code? Are you using `geom_line`? Maybe you want `geom_path`? But that still won't do whatever smoothing has been applied to the data in calc-sheet.

Comment: @KonradRudolph as you can see X_value are (in order) ... 146,2009493; 150,5234121; 150,0431385... and so on,  but it seems that ggplot uses 146,2009493; 150,0431385;  150,5234121

Comment: @Tung this is the code i used `require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame( Y_Value = c(11.28722382, 11.33209991, 12.87083524, 13.87191672, 16.89631805, 20.27088036, 17.57803852, 16.89684937, 13.21146656, 12.37363526, 15.50079491), X_Value = c(130.9169466, 136.0021971, 139.7313807, 142.1610003, 146.2009493, 150.5234121, 150.0431385, 153.0377859, 153.9700818, 157.0212321, 164.1970854))

ggplot(df, aes(x = X_Value, y = Y_Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()`

Comment: @MrFlick using `geom_path` the points are connected correctly